# What is the best performance search query/method for huge number of records

Tags: mysql, search

I need to know what's the best way to search tables with million records. I have a table called  and this table has the column:

Status might be more than one word like:

"I am happy today and the weather is nice".

Also, it might be in different languages.

Records in table are represented by UTF-8.

I need to search for a sub-word, word, or even some words out of the whole sentence like for example (according the status above):

Search 1: keyword = "ppy"

Search 2: keyword = "am weather"

Search 3: keyword = "nice"

Search 4: keyword = "day weath"

I would greatly appreciate if you hint me to the best method to apply a robust search. As far as I know using "LIKE" is not practical for huge records. I heard about the full text index but never used that.

Thank you very much!

Cheers,

Comment: if you want to search over a huge data base i would suggest you for third party tool [ApexSql](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx)

Comment: Manage `indexes` for your table for text add the index `FULLTEXT`

Answer (score -2):

A text engine like [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is often your best bet.